# Haskell Control.Lens Traversing Prism

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

I have a deeply nested data structure, and I'm using Control.Lens.* to simplify accessing its values in a state monad.

So consider the following:

```
data Config = Config { _foo :: Maybe Int
                     , _bar :: Int
                     }

$(makeLenses ''Config)
```

How do I operate "functorially" over the Maybe?  I'd like to write an idiomatic getter that does:

```
config = Config (Just 1) 0
config^.foo.to fmap (+1) == Just 2
```

Better still, how would we handle the case when Config is nested deeper?

```
data Config = { _foo :: Maybe Foo }
data Foo = Foo { _bar :: Bar }
data Bar = Bar Int
$(makeLenses ''Bar)
$(makeLenses ''Foo)
```

Can we use the accessors foo and bar to Maybe return a modified Bar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to use a `Prism` to (maybe) go into the the `Just` branch.

```
>>> let config' = config & foo . _Just .~ (+1)
    in  config' ^. foo
Just 2
```

And then this `Prism` will compose just the same as other lenses, forming `Traversal`s.

```
foo . _Just . bar . _Bar :: Traversal' Config Int
```

Take a look at some tutorials I wrote on lens that spend a little time examining how `Lens` and `Prism` relate:

https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial

https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/lens-aeson-traversals-prisms

Comment: You could also use `mapped` or `traverse` instead of `_Just` in this case.

Comment: Thanks.  I kept trying to do things like "traverse _Just".  In other words, I thought I had to use a combinator "on" the prism.  I guess I lost my grip on the types.

Comment: @nomen I spent a long time trying to do that as well when I was learning lenses. You get an intuition in Haskell for passing functions "under" a Functor, but with lens the strategy is instead to specify the path "through" the Functor. At least that's how I think about it—it's definitely a different style.

Comment: Nice article. I found the introduction to Lenses to be really great, but Prism only lists negative examples. I've been trying for over an hour and still can't figure out how write an expression with prisms that typechecks! What is the equivalent of `view _1 ("goal", "chaff")` for prisms?

Comment: > Nevermind, I finally got it: `import Control.Lens; import Control.Lens.Fold; import Control.Lens.Prism; preview _Left (Left "hi")`. Victory!!!